# Designing a view in iOS application

Tags: ios, view, uiscrollview

I'm working on adding a "privacy policy" screen for my iOS application.  As you know a privacy policy or 'Terms of Service' contract contains lot of texts in paragraphs. Initially I thought I could just add a scrollview (vertical) and add multiple labels and textviews. But as I start to design this I start to wonder if am I on correct path or if there is a method to do this logically. Any help hint or direction would be really useful.

Comment: Use scroll view and UITextview in it.

Comment: Concatenate your all strings into single and now show this string into webview or textview. (This is simplest one.)

Comment: You can make use of WebViews to display TOS and privacy policy. Any app that u develop happen to have websites then they will anyway develop it and u can reuse them. Simply load their url in your webView. TOS and privacy usually have Bold , italics kind of styling so u cant render them as plain text u would need Attributed text, getting Attributed text or HTML text n then converting it to attributed text just to show dumb piece of text is not worth. So consider webview

Comment: @VikasDhasal `UItextview` have `scrollView` property, So there is no logic of using `UITextview` in `scroll view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply display the privacy policy / terms of service web page on `UIWebView` or `WKWebView` ? Provided the web design is [**responsive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design). That would save all the trouble of text formatting to scrolling and other event handling.